# Default function in python shell

Tags: python, customization, read-eval-print-loop

Entering an expression in Python shell outputs the `repr()` of the expression.

Is it possible to set this default function to some user defined function?

Comment: Are you looking to change what the `repr()` of an object is or change the actual function the shell calls?

Comment: Check out [rjb's answer on this other question](/a/43618365/4518341) for a nice implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook):

> `sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an expression entered in an interactive Python session. The display of these values can be customized by assigning another one-argument function to `sys.displayhook`.

Normal behaviour:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 25, 15, 26, 1, 772968)
```

then

```
>>> import sys
>>> def new_hook(value):
...   sys.stdout.write(str(value))
...   sys.stdout.write("\n")
... 
>>> sys.displayhook = new_hook
```

modified behaviour:

```
>>> datetime.now()
2021-11-25 15:26:14.177267
```